# How do you define a mutable pointer to a const object?

Tags: c++, pointers, constants, mutable

I have a class that contains a pointer to a constant VARIANT value outside the class, but sometimes I want to change this pointer to refer to a VARIANT member object of the class itself.

Most instances of this class will be const, so I have to declare the pointer as mutable.

In Visual C++ this code seems to do what I want:

```
VARIANT mutable const* m_value;
```

However, since mutable is meant to be a property of the pointer and not the pointee, I would think this to be the correct syntax:

```
VARIANT const * mutable m_value;
```

Similar to how you define a constant pointer (and not a pointer to a const object). Visual C++ does not accept this variant though.

*warning C4518: 'mutable ' : storage-class or type specifier(s) unexpected here; ignored*

Is Visual C++ right, or am I missing something? Could another more standard-conformant compiler behave differently?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Comeau online](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/tryitout/) seems to agree with VC++ here.

And it also makes sense! A class member can only be mutable once and there *is no such thing* as a *non-const pointer to a mutable const object*. "Mutable const object" doesn't make sense.

You should put the `mutable` in front of your declaration, as it is in the same area as, for example, `static`:

```
class A {
  static  int const* m_p1; // static modifiable pointer to a const object;
  mutable int const* m_p2; // mutable pointer to a const object
  ...
  mutable int *const m_p3; // DOES NOT MAKE sense
```

`m_p3` does not make sense - you declare the member as "always mutabel" and as "always const" at the same time.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! (and the tip about Comeau online, might come in handy in the future). Yeah, I guess it makes more sense that mutable behaves (and "binds") similar to static and not as const.

Answer (score 7):

VC++ is right. In this case `mutable` is a storage-class-specifier, like `static`, `extern` and `register`. Just like

```
int const* static foo;
```

won't compile, as a specifier must appear at the beginning of a declaration.

Comment: Thanks, that was a short and succinct answer! I'll take care not to confuse storage class specifiers and type qualifiers in the future.

Answer (score -2):

See [How do you define a mutable pointer to a const object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4104941/how-do-you-define-a-mutable-pointer-to-a-const-object/4105024#4105024)

Comment: This doesn't address the question.